# How to import jar files when running an individual class through terminal

Tags: java, shell

I have written this but I don't know how to add the `jar` file to this script.

```
/darshan/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java com.supplier.external.DeleteTableData arg1
```

But this is not running since I couldn't import the related `jar` files here. How to do this?

Comment: where is your `jar` file?

Answer (score 0):

```
/rezsystem/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java -classpath pathToPgSQLDriverJar;pathToYourProgramClassesAndJars attraction.external.viator.DeleteTableData
```

Will this work ? If the jar is not there on that machine, you will have to upload it there.

say your postgres driver jar is pg.jar located at usr/darshan/myjars/pg.jar. Your DeleteTableData program is located at folder /usr/darshan/myprogs/attraction/external/viator/DeleteTableData, then your command will look like

```
/rezsystem/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java -classpath /usr/darshan/myjars/pg.jar:/usr/darshan/myprogs attraction.external.viator.DeleteTableData
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please clarify this more

Answer (score 0):

/darshan/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java -classpath PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR  com.supplier.external.DeleteTableData arg1

Comment: I have tried as below but its not working.Its throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. /rez/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java  mypath/postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3.jar mypath.DeleteTableData args

Comment: try this: java -classpath   /rez/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java -classpath  ".;mypath/*" mypath.DeleteTableData args

Comment: you have not use -classpath  parameter. The classpath should contains both your mypath.DeleteTableData＇s path(the .; ) and your jdbc3.jar＇s path(the mypath/* ),so i use  -classpath ".;mypath/*"

Comment: Thank you for your support Below method works fine for me java -cp :/Office/tmp/viator/postgresql-8.0-311.jdbc3.jar: test.ext.via.DeleteTableData arg